# Universal Analytics Ecommerce - Dead?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce

I must be missing something. But this isn't tracking at all. Even when I do a test send in firebug, it just.. doesn't do anything. I also get the message "undefined"

The loader:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
ga('create', 'UA-MYUA-1', 'MYDOMAINNAME.com');
ga('send', 'pageview');
ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js');
```

How I'm tracking:

```
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id': data.orderId,
    'affiliation': '',
    'revenue': data.total,
    'shipping:': 0,
    'tax': 0
});

ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id': data.orderId,
    'name': data.productName,
    'sku': data.productSlug,
    'category:': '$'+data.productPrice,
    'price': data.productPrice,
    'quantity': quantity
});

ga('ecommerce:send');
```

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: What's the full error message? Can you share URL?

Comment: No error messages. Just get "defined" when running anything in firebug. Seems normal, as I can use ga('send', 'pageview') and get the same result.

Comment: You seem to know what you're doing - think you could take the time to email me and I'll send? Attempting to be discrete on the site itself. If so, thanks! talasan@nicholsonws.com works.

Comment: Hi there - are you sure you are passing on correct data-types? Especially integers when it comes to price/quantity...

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=376

Comment: @PetrHavlík the google examples show all values as strings. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: Can you dump data / quantity variables?

Comment: @MisterPhilip the problem occurs even when following the examples found here. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce

Comment: @Blowsie - I'm seeing 3 pings from the code you provided using dummy data. You mention you're sending this in firebug - are you checking the net tab to see if a request was sent (should total 3 requests)? Do you have an adblocker or 'Do Not Track' settings enabled? If so, disable those.

Comment: also can you put `ga('require', 'ecommerce', 'ecommerce.js'); ` before `ga('send', 'pageview');`. I am not sure if this is critical, but usually i use it this way. Hope this helps you

Answer (score 0):

Your code has extra : in them for shipping and category.

'shipping:': should be 'shipping':

Also your integers and doubles need to be between ' as provided in the examples in https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce